# SOCP: minimize sum of euclidean norms

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization, mosek

I need to optimize a portfolio given side constraints on the past performance of the portfolio (in terms of Value-at-Risk).
A simplified version of my problem is

```
min t
s.t. t >= (w'H1w)^0.5 + (w'H2w)^0.5 = ||G1w||_2 + ||G2w||_2           (1)
          ...
```

where H1 and H2 are covariance matrices and w is a vector of portfolio weights. G1 and G2 are such that H = G'G. The dots indicate other constraints which I omit for brevity.

According to the [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378426612000623), this is a second-order cone problem. I tried to do this in Mosek but I do not see how I could write (1) as a cone. If I had to minimize the sum of the variances, the task would be easy, but unfortunately, I have to minimize the sum of the standard deviations.

How can I write (1) in terms of a (rotated) quadratic cone?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question of mathematics.  Linear programming (of which SOCP is a variation) is not programming as generally accepted here on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to split the sum into two terms. You can write for example

```
min t1+t2 s.t. t1 >= (w'H1w)^0.5 and t2 >= (w'H2w)^0.5
```

and each constraint can be represented using a quadratic cone.